# 502 bad gateway when deploying using app engine service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have used `app engine service` to deploy my react app where i have used `create-react-app`. I deployed my app as follow

`gcloud auth login`
`gcloud config set project travelappfrontend`
`gcloud app deploy`

In this process, it did not show me any error instead got successful message. However, when i open the url it generated, it consumes very much time and says `502 bad gateway`. Do i need to consider any other things?

here is my app.yaml

```
service: frontend-app
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: build
```

when i see the logs, i get only eslint related warnings

Here is the logs in detail. a new one i created again by stopping previous version. the logs i generated using `gcloud app logs read`

```
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 7:23:  'PrivateRoute' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 7:37:  'AdminRoute' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 11:8:  'loadable' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Home/FootNote/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 7:8:   'theme' is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 53:3:  'Address' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Guides/List/List.js
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 90:3:  'Text' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
2019-11-20 16:39:07 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  Compiled with warnings.
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/commons/Sidebar/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 122:41:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function                                                                       array-callback-return
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 127:48:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 151:34:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function                                                                       array-callback-return
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 156:44:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Authentication/Login/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 13:10:  'isAdmin' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 16:10:  'ResendDiv' is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 22:19:  'changeMessage' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 23:11:  'refetchUser' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Guides/Form/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 14:17:  'loading' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Guides/List/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 17:17:  'loading' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 17:26:  'refetch' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 102:7:  'Wrapper' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Authentication/ForgotPassword/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 17:19:  'changeMessage' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Admin/Guide/Create/Form.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 17:3:   'AutoSuggestion' is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 29:3:   'SPECIALIZATION' is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 41:5:   'getRootProps' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 42:5:   'getInputProps' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 43:5:   'isDragActive' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 44:5:   'isDragAccept' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 45:5:   'isDragReject' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 236:3:  'DropzoneContainer' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 251:3:  'ThumbsContainer' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 257:3:  'Thumb' is assigned a value but never used              no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 267:3:  'ThumbInner' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 272:3:  'Image' is assigned a value but never used              no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Home/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 22:10:  'isOpen' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Guides/Detail/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 23:17:  'loading' is assigned a value but never used           no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 112:3:  'BannerHolder' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 116:3:  'CoverImage' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 122:3:  'Info' is assigned a value but never used              no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 132:3:  'OtherDetail' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 138:3:  'GuideDetail' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 148:3:  'GuideMetaInfo' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 152:3:  'GuidePrice' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 159:3:  'Brk' is assigned a value but never used               no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 166:3:  'Inclusion' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 177:3:  'RequestGuidBtn' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 180:3:  'Row' is assigned a value but never used               no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 191:3:  'ThreeCol' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 203:3:  'WhiteCol' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 209:3:  'VerifyList' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 212:3:  'VerifyListItem' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 219:3:  'VerfiedIcon' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 224:3:  'NineColumn' is assigned a value but never used        no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 238:3:  'FlexCol' is assigned a value but never used           no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 242:3:  'FlexRow' is assigned a value but never used           no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 245:3:  'Key' is assigned a value but never used               no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 251:3:  'Value' is assigned a value but never used             no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 258:3:  'Headline' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 267:3:  'ProfileChatLinks' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 270:3:  'ProfileChatLink' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 274:3:  'UpcomingTable' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 287:3:  'TrekRowHead' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 294:3:  'TrekName' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 304:3:  'TrekDays' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/commons/Table/EditableField/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 23:37:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Admin/Guide/Create/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 25:17:  'loading' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Guides/Form/Form.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 25:3:  'SAFETY_TRAINING' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Authentication/ResetPassword/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 2:21:   'SubmissionError' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 9:10:   'splitToken' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 14:11:  'location' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Home/Listings/TopDestination/TopDestinationListing/destination-list.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 3:8:  'styled' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Authentication/Confirmation/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 40:3:  'SButton' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 43:3:  'ConfirmationBtn' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 46:3:  'Wrapper' is assigned a value but never used          no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Home/Header/Search.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 55:1:  Block is redundant  no-lone-blocks
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Admin/Guide/List/List.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 57:17:  'loading' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Authentication/Signup/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 5:10:   'isEmpty' is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 8:8:    'setSession' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 14:11:  'refetchUser' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/commons/Route/AdminRoute.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 6:10:  'isAdmin' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/App/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 7:23:  'PrivateRoute' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 7:37:  'AdminRoute' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 11:8:  'loadable' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Home/FootNote/index.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 7:8:   'theme' is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 53:3:  'Address' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  ./src/components/Guides/List/List.js
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]    Line 90:3:  'Text' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]  To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
2019-11-20 16:39:51 frontend-app[20191120t202725]
2019-11-20 16:50:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:50:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 16:50:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 16:50:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:50:47 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:50:47 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 16:50:47 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 16:50:47 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:51:07 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 16:51:07 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:51:12 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 16:51:12 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:53:57 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:53:57 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 16:53:57 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 16:53:57 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 16:54:23 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 16:54:23 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:00:40 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:00:40 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 17:00:40 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 17:00:40 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:00:49 default[20191119t221618]  "GET /" 404
2019-11-20 17:01:06 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 17:01:06 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:03:47 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  "GET /" 502
2019-11-20 17:06:08 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  "GET /favicon.ico" 502
2019-11-20 17:10:39 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! errno 1
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! nodetravel@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR!
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! Failed at the nodetravel@0.1.0 start script.
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-20 17:10:41 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-20T17_10_41_727Z-debug.log
2019-11-20 17:10:48 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:10:48 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 17:10:48 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 17:10:48 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:11:26 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 17:11:26 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:13:50 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:13:50 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 17:13:50 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 17:13:50 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:09 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:09 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 17:14:09 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 17:14:09 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:16 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 17:14:16 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:27 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:27 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > nodetravel@0.1.0 start /app
2019-11-20 17:14:27 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  > react-scripts start
2019-11-20 17:14:27 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:33 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 17:14:33 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
2019-11-20 17:14:51 frontend-app[20191120t222924]  Starting the development server...
2019-11-20 17:14:51 frontend-app[20191120t222924]
```

Comment: Add some more console.log() and provide exact log. `502 bad gateway` can throw for many reasons. Any log on App Engine Log? Better to provide some console log from App Engine. Also try `gcloud components update1 and `gcloud app deploy` in verbose mode.

Comment: how to do console log from app engine? Do you mean to say `gcloud app logs read`?

Comment: Easiest option --- Go to Cloud Console > App Engine > Services > on Table view right side, Diagonise Column > Drop Down > Logs .... You may need to click "Load newer logs". [link]https://imgur.com/hszyde3

Comment: i am getting only eslint related issues in the logs that is also eslint warning.

Comment: Please post detailed logs

Comment: updated with detailed logs.

Comment: Hard to tell.. Can you please explain what you are trying to do actually? It may happen your application not able to connect DB (if you are using at all).  REMEMBER : These logs will show the logs specified in your application. Can you pls elaborate what you are trying to do? Are you using DB? Where is that? How you are connecting that? Any log for successful connection?

Comment: I tried using production environment api from local react server and I am not having any problem while fetching the items from production api.

Comment: Are you sure your GCP App Engine can connect and fetch data from your `production environment api` ?

Comment: I am not sure from GCP App Engine but from localhost:3000 its connecting and fetching data from prod api. Also i tried from https://storage.googleapis.com/travelfrontend/index.html and then clicked on the link which shows the list of guides where it is showing the guides list. I have a xml issue problem while refreshing in storage bucket(as i do not have domain ready so just for demo purpose) so i am trying to use app engine service.

Comment: Localhost may connect your Prod environment. Your local environment may also connect Google APIs if your system is having Internet Connection. BUT... That doesn't mean YOUR APP ENGINE CAN CONNECT YOUR PROD SERVER. Did you try to PING your Production Server HostName from App Engine? If not Please try it. You can check here - [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping

Comment: where should i write ping code to check if prod server is active or not?

Comment: when you told `That doesn't mean YOUR APP ENGINE CAN CONNECT YOUR PROD SERVER.` I then find out ip address of the domain for frontend application and put it in the authorized network address on database server and it worked.

Comment: Sounds great. Hope your problem has been resolved.